# Add file to Wix installer if it exists

Tags: wix, components, conditional-statements, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to add a file to the installer like this in my main wxs file.

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="Files" Directory="Bin">
        <?if $(var.FILE_EXISTS) = "true"?>
            <Component>
                <Condition>$(var.FILE_EXISTS) = "true"</Condition>
                <File Source="$(var.SourceDir)/file.txt"/>
            </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

I'm passing FILE_EXISTS through candle.exe with the -d option

But its not taking effect. Its  not getting added. It works when I don't have the conditions (just the File element).  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to do this because the file exists only in some branches and all branches use the same installer script.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the condition you are talking about is a build-time condition. Basically, you would like to control whether the file in question gets into the MSI package.

If that's correct, then one mistake is the `<Condition>` element under `<Component>`. That's install-time condition, and only influences then the file is installed.

The other one is a pure syntax issue. The `<?if?>` directive must have the closing element.

Taking the above into account, your snippet might look like this:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="Files" Directory="Bin">
  <?if $(var.FILE_EXISTS) = "true"?>
  <Component>
    <File Source="$(var.SourceDir)/file.txt"/>
  </Component>
  <?endif?>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yan. The extra condition element was it. Took that out and it worked!!

Comment: Great to know it helped! Don't forget to accept the helpful answer above ;-)

Comment: I get the error `Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.FILE_EXISTS)'.` What is the pitfall? Maybe it's not allowed to have a condition for the &lt;Component&gt; inside of a &lt;Directory&gt; structure?